# How to allow installation only to a specific folder?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to install my setup content only to one specific directory, so I want to have the `Next` button on directory selection page disabled, unless the user chooses the right folder to install to.

How can I disable the `Next` button on directory selection page and enable it right after user chooses a specific directory ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Wouldn't be *the Next button is greyed until the user chooses the right folder* quite misleading ? What if I as the user forget the right directory ? Wouldn't be better to disable the *choose folder* edit box or skip that page at all ?

Comment: Since the installation directory isn't the same on every computer and the program doesn't have any registry keys to read the installation path from, it wouldn't be better. The user won't forget the right directory, since I have a readme file and the installer also has custom texts to aid the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following sample shows how to disable the `Next` button when you reach the `SelectDir` page and enable it only when you enter (or choose from the browse directory dialog) the `C:\MySecretDir` folder (the `MySecretDir` constant). The comparing is case insensitive since user can enter whatever he (or she) wants.

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
const
  MySecretDir = 'C:\MySecretDir';

procedure OnDirEditChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := CompareText(WizardDirValue, MySecretDir) = 0;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
    OnDirEditChange(nil);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.DirEdit.OnChange := @OnDirEditChange;
end;
```

Or if you want to enable the `Next` button only if there's a specific file `MyUniqueFile.exe` in the chosen directory, modify the code in `OnDirEditChange` event handler this way:

```
procedure OnDirEditChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := FileExists(AddBackslash(WizardDirValue) +
    'MyUniqueFile.exe');
end;
```

Comment: What can I say? Perfect, just the thing I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems more user friendly to just do the check in NextButtonClick, throw a message box in case it fails, and make the function return false. This way you can notify the user _why_ he can't continue. Also, disabling the button probably won't have any effect on silent installs, whereas making NextButtonClick return false _does_.

Comment: @Nyerguds, yes, might be; I just answered the asked question. About the silent setup, it won't have any effect as this question asks about user's selection.

Comment: @TLama Why would the LowerCase() function shown here not work for me if I'm running 5.5.5?

Comment: Actually, it works for me by itself but not inside a StringChangeEX() function for some reason.

Comment: @RichC, the `LowerCase` function works with ASCII character set (so it's limited), but without knowing any further details (like example input) it's not possible to help you. Better ask a new question. However, the `LowerCase` function is not good here, I'll replace that comparison with `CompareText`.

Comment: I just separated it outside of the StringChangeEX and it works now - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could stop users from changing the install directory, by disabling the directory selection page. When disable the page will not be shown during the install.

```
[SETUP]
DisableDirPage=yes
```

Comment: That's right, however the OP's requirement was *I want to have the Next button on directory selection page disabled, unless the user chooses the right folder to install to.*