# InnoSetup - What is the textbox name in the folder selection dialog?

Tags: dialog, inno-setup, folderbrowserdialog

Can you modify the default folder selection dialog in InnoSetup? I mainly need to change the folder path textbox in this dialog. When the user clicks the Next button it needs to check if the folder path given is "C:\Data1". If this path is given then it needs to be changed to "C:\Data".

Comment: Usung the textbox is the wrong way, there is a dedicated API for checking and adjusting the PATH.

Comment: What is the API?

Comment: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/, Pascal Scripting

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked,

```
[code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  case CurPageID of
    wpSelectDir:
      begin
        if WizardForm.DirEdit.Text = 'C:\Data1' then 
          WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := 'C:\Data';
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks to these links,

[Get the path in the wpSelectDir before {app} is set Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44014506/get-the-path-in-the-wpselectdir-before-app-is-set-inno-setup)

[How to allow installation only to a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070493/how-to-allow-installation-only-to-a-specific-folder)

[Inno Setup with three destination folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657175/inno-setup-with-three-destination-folders)